# How to deal with data returned from $.getJSON asynchronously

Tags: ajax, getjson

I've been testing code using the [mockJSON](http://experiments.mennovanslooten.nl/2010/mockjson/) library to simulate data loads.

My code looks like this at the client/consumer level:

```
            var jsonDataFeed= new DataLoader_EUJP();
            jsonDataFeed.grabJson(0);
            var someVariable = jsonDataFeed.Data;
....
```

The `grabJson()` method is what calls `$.getJSON`

This worked fine as long as it was mockJSON providing me the data, but now of course it's an asynchronous call, and I can't be sure my data is there when `someVariable` is set.  I got used to having data immediately returned and didn't think twice about it.

What's recommended for making sure an asynchronous data load is completed before using that data?

Comment: The link you provide shows you. `function(json) {
    // this will be mocked
}`

Comment: Right, that's where I store the data (via `this.data = json`).  The problem I'm having is in the execution flow above, where the next line of code runs before that callback is called.  Not sure if I should put my subsequent logic into that callback or if there are other approaches?

Comment: Yes, everything has to happen in the callback, as that's the only time you are guaranteed to have the data (not counting network errors, etc). But the callback approach has somewhat fallen out of favour and been replaced with promises. See this quote - *"The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise"* from here - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link to jQuery promises-- I'd heard of them but need to learn more.